# How to create an executable file for Linux machine using Pyinstaller?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, tkinter, ubuntu-14.04, pyinstaller

I have written a small GUI Desktop application using python on Ubuntu 14.04(64-bit). I wanted an executable version of my code so it can run on other linux machines. I was able to create executable for Windows and Mac. But on Linux the created binary file does not work.

**For windows:** the command i used to make the code executable was

```
pyinstaller -D -F -n main -w "main.py"
```

this worked fine on other windows(64-bit) machine too.

**For mac:**

```
pyinstaller --windowed "main.py"
```

Worked fine.

**for linux:** i tried

```
pyinstaller main.py
```

as well as

```
pyinstaller -D -F -n main -w "main.py"
```

im unable to open the binary file 
[image: this is displayed when i open the executable]

i tried changing the permissions using `chmod`, still the same error.

I am using:

- python 2.7 - 64bit
- pyinstaller 2.1
- Tkinter

Comment: The command for Mac is somehow creating a jpg file for me!

Comment: Try giving the same command as windows or Linux for Mac too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pyinstaller 2.1 was the problem. Installing `dev` version of pyinstaller(version `2.1.1dev-`) worked.

Comment: Did you create Exe from Linux environment?

Comment: I did. But its a binary file,.. Not an `exe`. And for some wierd reason, that binary file was working only when it was under home directory.. ie,. Say for example, under the path /`home/username`. And the OS was Ubuntu 14.4

Comment: and how did you run in windows?

Comment: You mean , how I created exe for windows?

Comment: I am on mac and want to create executable that could run on Windows as I dont have a windows machine. I want to generate exec file within my Mac environment for Windows user

Comment: You can't create exe for windows machine on a Mac system. You need respective OS to create executables to work under that OS

Comment: @Volatil3 one can fetch a pre-built Windows virtual machine directly from Microsoft and build inside it: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto , If I create an exe under Windows 10, will the same exe be able to run on other Windows version?

Comment: @Jdeep it should work. You could try building both on Windows 10 and Windows 7 just in case.

Answer (score 11):

I tried in my Ubuntu:

```
pyinstaller -D -F -n main -c "main.py"
```

and it created a working binary.

Comment: what the flags mean?

Comment: @Lucas -D for creating in one-folder bundle containing the executable, -F for creating one-file bundled executable, -n is the name, -c is to open a console window for standard i/o

Comment: @crysal What if console is NOT desired? Which flag to use then?